# Injective model structure on sheaves of bounded complexes of $A$-modules

Tags: cohomology, model-categories, derived-categories, sheaf-cohomology, chain-complexes

The following might be very well known for people who works with model categories, but I do not find the answer.

Let $A$-be a ring. Denote $\mathbf{Ch}_+(A)$ the category of positive degree cochain complexes of $A$-modules (complexes where differential rises the degree and which are zero in negative degree). There is the *injective model structure* on $\mathbf{Ch}_+(A)$ which has quasi-isomorphisms as weak equivalences, monomorphisms as cofibrations and epimorphisms with injective kernel as fibrations. Let $K^\bullet$ be a complex, then its injective resolution $I^\bullet (K^\bullet)$ turn out to be its fibrant replacement.

Let $X$ be a topological space and consider $\mathbf{Ch}_+(\mathbf{Shv}_X(A))$, the category of positive complexes of sheaves of $A$-modules on $X$. My question is the following:

**Question:** *Is there an analogue model structure in $\mathbf{Ch}_+(\mathbf{Shv}_X(A))$ to the injective model structure in  $\mathbf{Ch}_+(A)$?* More concretely, if we consider quasi-isomorphisms as weak equivalences, monomorphisms as cofibrations, and morphisms having the right lifting property with respect to injective quasi-isomorphisms, *do they define a model structure?* If $\mathcal{K^\bullet}$ is a complex of sheaves, *will its injective resolution $I^\bullet (\mathcal{K}^\bullet)$ be its fibrant replacement?*

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer just now, but I think the answer is probably yes, and that proof should use cotorsion pairs. I recommend you look at the work of Hovey and Gillespie. Gillespie has a paper handling categories of chain complexes of quasi-coherent sheaves over a scheme, and perhaps some mention is made there of the case you care about. I believe there are two cotorsion pairs in these settings, one for the projective model structure and one for the injective.

Comment: I think that, in all cases, cofibrations should be cochain maps which are mono in strictly positive degrees (not necessarily in degree $0$), so that the $t$-structure truncation functor from the unbounded category is a left Quillen functor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David White's comment led me to adequate references to answer this question. Thank you very much

**Question:** *Is there an analogue model structure in $\mathbf{Ch}_+(\mathbf{Shv}_X(A))$ to the injective model structure on $\mathbf{Ch}_+(A)$?*  More concretely, if we consider quasi-isomorphisms as weak equivalences, monomorphisms as cofibrations, and morphisms having the right lifting property with respect to injective quasi-isomorphisms, *do they define a model structure?*

**Answer:** Yes, there is such model structure. The above mentioned three clasess do form a model structure. Find the result in a [letter to A. Grothendieck](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~georges.maltsiniotis/ps/lettreJoyal.ps) from Joyal in Théorème 2 (p.10)

**Question:** If $\mathcal{K}^\bullet$ is a complex of sheaves, *will its injective resolution $I^\bullet(\mathcal{K}^\bullet)$ be its fibrant replacement?*

**Answer:** Yes, it will. The same argument that shows that for a chain complex of modules its fibrant replacement is a complex made of injective modules holds for sheaves. Find the argument for modules (although the case of projective resolutins) in [this paper](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~gdungan/MC10.04.07.pdf),

Comment: Great! Glad you got it resolved!