# Concrete examples of derived categories

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, derived-categories, examples

What examples of abelian categories $\mathcal{A}$ are there such that the derived category $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$ can be described concretely? For example, is there a concrete way of describing $\mathcal{D}(A-\text{mod})$ for a suitable algebra $A$? When $A$ is semi-simple then the derived category is just ${\left(A-\text{mod}\right)}^{\mathbb{Z}}$. But what about non-semi-simple $A$? Are there easy to understand examples?

Comment: Can you please say more about what you would be content with in terms of "a concrete way of describing"? For example, in many situations there is a model structure, and we can compute morphism sets in the derived category via fibrant (injective resolution) and cofibrant (projective resolution) replacements. Is that concrete enough?

Comment: It's relatively easy to classify the indecomposables in the bounded derived category of $k[t]/(t^2)$, but already $k[t]/(t^3)$ will give you a severe headache.

Comment: @DavidWhite Yes, I'd say calculating the Hom sets would be a concrete description (since the objects of the derived category are clear). Of course this just replaces "concrete way of describing" with "calculating", but well...

Answer (score 5):

One way to concretely describe derived categories is via the framework of model categories, and from [the comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467522/concrete-examples-of-derived-categories?noredirect=1#comment1213711_467522), it sounds like the OP is satisfied with this approach. Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit. Then there is a projective model structure $M$ on $Ch(R)$, whose homotopy category is the derived category $D(R)$ of $R$-modules. Weak equivalences are quasi-isomorphisms, all objects are fibrant, and cofibration is related to projective resolution. Hence, morphisms in $D(R)$ can be computed as $Hom_{D(R)}(X,Y) = M(X^c,Y)$ where $X^c$ is the cofibrant replacement of $X$. No semi-simplicity of $R$ is needed, though that assumption certainly makes it easier to compute projective resolutions.

If computing projective resolutions is hard, an alternative is the injective model structure with the same weak equivalences, all objects cofibrant, and fibrant replacement related to injective resolution. Now morphisms in the derived category are $M(X,Y^f)$, using fibrant replacement. Details on both model structures can be found [on the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+chain+complexes). There's also a [flat model structure](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2004-356-08/S0002-9947-04-03416-6/S0002-9947-04-03416-6.pdf) where the cofibrations are monomorphisms with dg-flat cokernels (so, cofibrant replacement is like finding a flat cover), and fibrations are the epimorphisms with dg-cotorsion kernels.

More generally, if $\mathcal A$ is an abelian category with a [pair of compatible cotorsion pairs](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ebshipley/hovey.pdf), or a Hovey triple, then the [same machinery can be used](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-002-0431-9) to construct a model structure on $Ch(\mathcal A)$ and thereby get at the derived category $D(\mathcal A)$. I've written before about such examples:

[Model structures on the category of unbounded chain complexes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107710/model-structures-on-the-category-of-unbounded-chain-complexes)

[Injective model structure on sheaves of bounded complexes of $A$-modules](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215989/injective-model-structure-on-sheaves-of-bounded-complexes-of-a-modules)

As you can see from the second link, this works also for sheaves of bounded complexes, and quasi-coherent sheaves. Check out [this survey](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/blms/bdw051) of the theory of cotorsion pairs, for lots of examples of abelian model categories $\mathcal A$.

For a more down-to-earth approach, avoiding model categories, I recommend chapter 10 of [Weibel's book](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/weibel-hom.pdf). This still shows the power of projective/injective resolutions for computing hom spaces in the derived category.

Comment: Which definition of semi-simplicity do you mean? Because mine is that every module is both projective and injective...

Comment: Yes, that's the standard definition. And of course, this implies that the global dimension is zero. Homological algebra is much easier. But, you don't need this in order to have a model structure or a good control over the derived category. What semi-simplicity buys you in abstract homotopy theory is well-explained in the following paper of Hovey: https://eudml.org/doc/130465

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link! I was convinced that semisimplicity trivializes the whole homological algebra in any imaginable circumstances. So you can imagine my surprise!